# Auto-renewable handling of magazine app with 2 issues every year

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a magazine app and want to implement auto-renewable subscriptions. There are **2** issues released every year. The first issue is released in **april** and the second issue a half year later in **october**.

If I implement a one-year subscription, how do I handle the subscription?

**Here are my problems:**

First: the user subscribed in August and is getting the april issue. Then in october the user is getting the october issue. In april next year the user has still a valid subscription but shouldn't get the april issue because his subscription ends in august. He only get the new april issue, if he renew the subscription.

**My second problem is:** I don't know if the user is renewing his subscription until august and can't deliver the new issue in april.

I hope you can understand the described problem and have some tips to put me in the right direction.